# Put data output from Sharepoint online list into an HTML table

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online

I have this code which is designed to get the most recent data from an underlying Sharepoint online list.  How do I adapt it to display the entire Sharepoint online list in an html table?

```
  private getLatestItemId(): Promise<number> {
return new Promise<number>((resolve: (itemId: number) => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
  //this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.properties.listName}')/items?$orderby=Id desc&$top=1&$select=id`,
  this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.properties.listName}')`,  
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'odata-version': ''
      }
    })
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: { Id: number }[] }> => {
      return response.json();
    }, (error: any): void => {
      reject(error);
    })
    .then((response: { value: { Id: number }[] }): void => {
      if (response.value.length === 0) {
        resolve(-1);
      }
      else {
        resolve(response.value[0].Id);
      }
    });
});
```

}
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be developing SPFx solution, you could bind data to [office UI Fabric DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist).

[Using Office UI Fabric Core and Fabric React in SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration)

You could check [my sample demo](https://github.com/OS-Lee/ReactSPFx/blob/master/src/webparts/reactSpFx/components/ReactSpFx.tsx) here to get SharePoint list data to an array objects.